# How can we add a project level configuration .gitattributes file to enforce line endings which will be applicable to anyone cloning the repo?

Tags: git, github, gitattributes

We are working in a project which has code in git and is developed using visual studio. But quite often we have this issue of having the whole file changed because of line endings getting changed automatically. We did consider the option of having line endings setting configured in git on every developer machine but we wanted something more tightly integrated to the repo we are using.
I was able to find a solution in the git documentation (https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) but right now I am stuck because I cannot commit this file to the repository since the .git folder is outside the repository. 
I tried to perform a "git add" for this file but that too did not work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the `.gitattributes` file at the root of the project work tree.  The location of the `.git` folder has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Placing the .gitattributes in project root with the following `text eol=lf` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I confirm:

- you can add and commit that `.gitattributes` files in the root folder
- you cannot reference that same file stored outside your repository through symlink (symbolic links).

Git 2.32 (Q2 2021) is very clear regarding the last point:

See [commit 8ff06de](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8ff06de10c12ef1f796fcefb96166133965d510e), [commit bb6832d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb6832d5529a75164acca7c0412657c96a9a5764), [commit 801ed01](https://github.com/git/git/commit/801ed010bf13465bf67608beabbaa1ec2550204f), [commit 1cb12f3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1cb12f3339086db5626a8003e3bd3398b968242a), [commit a1ca398](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a1ca398ba7da82622a9485400f88e62f3b756d1b) (03 May 2021), and [commit 43a2220](https://github.com/git/git/commit/43a2220f19eca9667dfac59a5e8a4deda2c3eb3d), [commit 0282f67](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0282f6799f2ca9c2d3f000976856282b7c69d238), [commit 9e1947c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9e1947cb482c8fc7e1d0c8334f126ced5062b895), [commit 963d02a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/963d02a24a1e6cec02cadf0d682af0bf222647ab) (01 May 2021) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 416449e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/416449eaba1ebe48b1637d1f4b0e257604353373), 11 May 2021)</sup>

> ### [`docs`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8ff06de10c12ef1f796fcefb96166133965d510e): document symlink restrictions for dot-files
>
> <sup>Suggested-by: Philip Oakley</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> We stopped allowing symlinks for `.gitmodules` files in [10ecfa7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/10ecfa76491e4923988337b2e2243b05376b40de) (`verify_path`: disallow symlinks in .gitmodules, 2018-05-04, Git v2.18.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7913f53b5628997165e075008d6142da1c04271a) listed in [batch #7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f15a486ca1dd67757cb6a3c0545dc2c6ef992bc3)) `(verify_path`: disallow symlinks in `.gitmodules`, 2018-05-04), and we stopped following symlinks for `.gitattributes`, `.gitignore`, and `.mailmap` in the commits from [204333b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/204333b015a663a339c855c72b86034203b66a6a) ("Merge branch 'jk/open-dotgitx-with-nofollow'", 2021-03-22, Git v2.32.0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/204333b015a663a339c855c72b86034203b66a6a)).
> The reasons are discussed in detail there, but we never adjusted the documentation to let users know.
>
> This hasn't been a big deal since the point is that such setups were mildly broken and thought to be unusual anyway.
> But it certainly doesn't hurt to be clear and explicit about it.

`gitattributes` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8ff06de10c12ef1f796fcefb96166133965d510e/Documentation/gitattributes.txt#L1250-L1255):

> ### NOTES
>
> Git does not follow symbolic links when accessing a `.gitattributes`
> file in the working tree.
>
> This keeps behavior consistent when the file
> is accessed from the index or a tree versus from the filesystem.

Same for [`.gitignore`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8ff06de10c12ef1f796fcefb96166133965d510e/Documentation/gitignore.txt#L152-L155), [`.mailmap`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8ff06de10c12ef1f796fcefb96166133965d510e/Documentation/gitmailmap.txt#L58-L64) and [`.gitmodules`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8ff06de10c12ef1f796fcefb96166133965d510e/Documentation/gitmodules.txt#L101-L108).